# TableView definition conflict with previous using CoreData in Mutable array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsmutablearray

I am trying to access the CoreData and putting it into the TableView so i have the data into the Mutable array but when i try to access it into the TableView then i got this error.

My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        var desc_arr: [String] = []
        var amt_arr: [String] = []

        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Expense")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {
            let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

            if results.count > 0 {

                for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

                    if let desc = result.valueForKey("desc") as? String {
                        print(desc)
                        desc_arr.append(desc)
                    }

                    if let amt = result.valueForKey("amt") as? String{
                        print(amt)
                        amt_arr.append(amt)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Fetch Failed")
        }

        print(desc_arr)
        print(amt_arr)

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return desc_arr.count
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            cell.textLabel?.text = desc_arr[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your datasource methods are embedded in viewDidLoad.  They need to be separate (but within the class definition).

Comment: What exactly is the error and where is it getting thrown?